# Issue display checkbox entity on other page

Tags: php, html

I have two files ***Add_Services.html*** and ***add_services.php***.

My database is named as '***ecc***'.

Database 'ecc' has a table named '***addservices***'.

Table '***addservices***' has fields '***id***', '***name***' and '***cost***'.

***Add_Services.html***

Add_Services.html has a ***button*** which ***onClick*** opens a ***pop-up window***.

**Add_Services.html**

```
<html>
<input type = "button" value = "Add Services"
onClick="MyWindow=window.open('add_services.php',
'MyWindow',width=600,height=300);
return false;">
</html>
```

***add_services.php***

***add_services.php*** display the checkbox list extracted from database '***ecc***' of table '***addservices***'. Pop-up is displaying two fields from table ***addservices*** and those are '***cost***' and '***name***'.

***add_services.php***

```
<html>
<body>
    <?php
        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "ecc");

        if(!$con){
            echo 'Not connected';
        }
        if(!mysqli_select_db($con,'ecc'))
        {
            echo 'db not selected';
        }

    $sql = "SELECT name, cost FROM addservices"; 
    $records = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($records,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    ?>



    <table width ="800" border="1" cellspacing="1">

    <tr>

    <th>
    Select
    </th>

    <th>
    Name
    </th>

    <th>
    Cost
    </th>

    </tr>

    <form action="" method = "POST">

  <?php


    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($records)){
        echo "<tr>";
        $n=$row['name'];
        $t=$row['cost'];
        echo "<td>";
        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='chkbox[]' value='{$row["name"]}'>";
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo "$n";
        echo "</td>";
        echo "\t";
        echo "<td>";
        echo "{$row["cost"]}";
        echo "</td>";

        echo "<br>";
        echo "</tr>";
  }
      ?>    

    </table>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">   
    </form>

    <?php

        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

            while(!empty($_POST['chkbox'])){

                echo "chkbox";

            }

        }

    ?>

  </body>
  </html>
```

My Issue: I am to display the checked content of check list on page ***Add_Services.html***

It would be grate if some one rewrite it.

Answer (score 0):

**The issue is :** you have not defined `name` of Submit Button

Change Incorrect Code :

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

**To Below Corrected Code :**

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
```

And, Also Instead of printing values of `chkbox[]` using while loop, Just use a simple `foreach` loop.

**Note :** Your code will go to infinite loop, as `$_POST['chkbox']` will always have value

So, Change Below Code :

```
while(!empty($_POST['chkbox'])){
    echo "chkbox";
}
```

To Below corrected code :

```
foreach($_POST['chkbox'] as $value)
    echo $value."\n";
```